# In TFS,How can I enforce a rule for checkins ,so that only overwrite and merge is not allowed on certain types of files

Tags: tfs

I am working on a LightSwitch Project,and there are lot of auto generated files in it .I want changes to be only ovewritten and disallow merges.
Can I enforce a TFS policy for the above requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the permission model and take away the merge permissions in the folders containing the Lightswitch project.

On file type you can mark the files to be "binary", but that's done by file extension. I suspect that it's conflict with other files of the same extension that do not fall under your policy.

[image]

This setting is stored at the collection level.

A final alternative is to create a custom checkin policy and check the list of proposed changes against your pattern. You can then deny the checkin. [It'd be very similar to this policy I've written a long time ago](https://github.com/jessehouwing/tfstools/blob/master/JesseHouwing.CheckinPolicies/WarnMultipleBranchPolicy.cs).